# Compute $E[X|\sigma (\mathbf 1_{X+Y=0})]$ for $X,Y$ iid Bernoulli

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Let $X, Y$ be iid Bernoulli distributed with parameter $p\in[0,1]$. Define $Z=\mathbf 1_{X+Y=0}$ and $\mathcal G=\sigma (Z)$
>
> Compute $E[X|\mathcal G]$ ( and $E[Y|\mathcal G]$ - are they independent?)

So we want $E[X|\sigma (\mathbf 1_{X+Y=0})]$ and
of course we have $\mathbb P[Z=1]=(1-p)^2 $ and $\mathbb P[Z=0]=1-(1-p)^2$.

But I can't really see the next rigorous step and struggle because one random variable is  discrete and one is continuous.

Comment: $p$ isn't a continuous random variable; it is a parameter (a constant with unknown value).

Comment: You are asked to calculate $E[X|\mathcal G]$  *and* $E[X|\mathcal G]$. Is one of these supposed to be $E[Y|\mathcal G]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X,Y\overset{iid}\sim\mathcal B(p)$ and  $Z=\mathbf 1_{X+Y=0}$, then:

$$\mathsf E(X\mid \sigma(Z)) {~=~ \mathsf P(X{=}1\mid Z{=}1)\cdot\mathbf 1_{Z=1} + \mathsf P(X{=}1\mid Z{=}0)\cdot\mathbf 1_{Z=0}\\~=~ \mathsf P(X{=}1\mid X{+}Y{=}0)\cdot\mathbf 1_{Z=1} + \mathsf P(X{=}1\mid X{+}Y{\neq}0)\cdot\mathbf 1_{Z=0} \\ ~\ddots}$$

Comment: Thank you, now I realise that the question was somehow stupid...
As the left Probability is zero we have in the end $\frac  {2}{3} \mathbf 1_{Z=0}$?

Comment: Not quite; $\mathsf P(X=1\mid X+Y\neq 0)~=~ \dfrac{\mathsf P(X=1)}{\mathsf P(X=1\cup Y=1)}~\underset{\tiny\text{generally}}\neq~\tfrac 23$.  @PeterGarder

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this as $X$ and $Y$ are independent? Or do I miss something?

Comment: @PeterGarder Independence doesn't cause this; it merely allows you to evaluate the probabilities, via $\mathsf P(X=1\cap Y=1)=\mathsf P(X=1)\,\mathsf P(Y=1)$

Comment: Now I am confused, which equations would be wrong then?

$\mathsf E(X\mid \sigma(Z)) = \mathsf P(X{=}1\mid X{+}Y{\neq}0)\cdot\mathbf 1_{Z=0}= \dfrac{\mathsf P(X=1)}{\mathsf P(X=1\cup Y=1)}\cdot\mathbf 1_{Z=0} = \dfrac{\mathsf P(X=1)}{\mathsf P(X=1)+\mathsf P(Y=1)- \mathsf P(X=1 \cap Y=1)}\cdot\mathbf 1_{Z=0} =\dfrac{\mathsf P(X=1)}{\mathsf P(X=1)+( Y=1)- P(X=1)( Y=1)}\cdot\mathbf 1_{Z=0}= \frac 2 3 \cdot\mathbf 1_{Z=0}$

Comment: @PeterGarder $X\sim\mathcal B(p)~\implies~\mathsf P(X{=}1)=p$

Comment: Oh I forgot and assumed $p=\frac 1 2 $
Thank you very much for your help!